# "Trying to get property of non-object" Inner Join using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

i try show data using PDO. But i get Error "Trying to get property of non-object".

i have a simple script.

```
public function tampilUserId($user_id)
{   
    $sql = "SELECT $this->user.*, $this->provinsi.*
            FROM $this->user
            INNER JOIN $this->provinsi 
            ON $this->user.provinsi_id=$this->provinsi.provinsi_id 
            WHERE user_id=:user_id";
    $stmt = db::prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

And this

```
echo $results->email_user;
print_r($result);
```

result

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\laporan_app\user_views\profile.php on line 35
>   stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 45 [nama_dpn_user] => [nama_blkng_user] => [username_user] => adi [password_user] => $2y$10$p/8gF5BcQSooQUKRlEAiPuOSy4o1RMeXA5Ul8GTZNYZi/4wcOP3Ja [email_user] => adi@gmail.com [level_user] => mahasiswa [img_user] => [_dir_img_user] => [_size_img_user] => [provinsi_id] => [universitas_id] => )

And i try this script

```
echo $results['email_user'];
print_r($results);
```

result

> Notice: Undefined index: email_user in C:\xampp\htdocs\laporan_app\user_views\profile.php on line 35
>   stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 45 [nama_dpn_user] => [nama_blkng_user] => [username_user] => adi [password_user] => $2y$10$p/8gF5BcQSooQUKRlEAiPuOSy4o1RMeXA5Ul8GTZNYZi/4wcOP3Ja [email_user] => adi@gmail.com [level_user] => mahasiswa [img_user] => [_dir_img_user] => [_size_img_user] => [provinsi_id] => [universitas_id] => )

Please help me, thanks before.

Comment: Di foreach dulu di `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`. Contoh : `$data =  $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); foreach($data as $d) { echo $d->email_user; }`

Comment: Sudah di coba bg, tetapi hasilnya sama juga.

Comment: Yg contoh dibawah sdh dicoba? `var_dump(tampilUserId($user_id))` isinya apa?

Comment: Try echo `$result->email_user` (not `$results`)

Comment: Saya coba script var_dump($results->email_user);
Hasilnya => Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\laporan_app\user\_views\profile.php on line 34
NULL

Comment: @YuriTkachenko $results

Answer (score 0):

Merdeka! :D

In case your SQL query not contain any error its mean data was successfully pulled from database. So in your `tampilUserId($user_id)` function, its returning set of array from `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`. Like below:

```
/* Sample from Sakila database */
array (size=603)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[11]
      public 'address_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'address' => string '47 MySakila Drive' (length=17)
      public 'address2' => null
      public 'district' => string 'Alberta' (length=7)
      public 'city_id' => string '300' (length=3)
      public 'postal_code' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'phone' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'last_update' => string '2014-09-25 22:30:27' (length=19)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[12]
      public 'address_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'address' => string '28 MySQL Boulevard' (length=18)
      public 'address2' => null
      public 'district' => string 'QLD' (length=3)
      public 'city_id' => string '576' (length=3)
      public 'postal_code' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'phone' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'last_update' => string '2014-09-25 22:30:09' (length=19)
      more elements...
```

All you need to do is looping your function returned value first whereever you call it. Short example from your case:

```
//I dont know you put it under class or not.
$data = $YourClass->tampilUserId($user_id);

foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo $item->email_user);
}
```

**Note:**

You can manually echoing your data without looping and its bad practice because you dont know the length of the array. So this is just gusessing. Taken from your case it would be.

```
$data = $YourClass->tampilUserId($user_id);
$data[0]->email_user; //If an object
$data[0]['email_user']; //If an array
```

---

### **Update:**

> There is suspicious thing on your query. The variable `$this->user` is not look like column name to me(unsure) If yes, so you have small mistake on your query. Secondly, as you said the result is `null` its mean something wrong or data you search not exist. I put this sample running inner join query.

---

### **Example:**

Lets said i had 2 table. 1st is ***address*** and 2nd is ***city***

|**address table**|

[image: Address table from Sakila database]

|**city table**|

[image]

So your sql query for joining table(from image above) should be:

```
SELECT adr.address_id, adr.address, adr.district, adr.city_id, c.city_id, 
c.city FROM address AS adr INNER JOIN city AS c ON adr.city_id = c.city_id  
WHERE c.city_id = 300  #using city id
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Bring it to PHP**

```
<?php
$pdo= new PDO('mysql:dbname=sakila;host=localhost:3306', 'user', password');

$city_id = 300; // manual set

$sql = 'SELECT adr.address_id, adr.address, adr.district, adr.city_id,  
       c.city_id, c.city FROM address AS adr INNER JOIN city AS c ON 
       adr.city_id = c.city_id WHERE c.city_id = :city_id';

$stmt = $_this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':city_id', $city_id);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>
```

`var_dump($data)` giving a result:

[image]

Great, as it come as `(object(stdClass))` so we can loop it through the array & then accessing it using `->` sign.

```
<?php
$i = 1;

foreach ($data as $d) {
    echo '<dl>';
    echo '<dt>Adress '.$i++.':</dt>';
    echo '<li>Address id: '.$d->address_id.'</li>';
    echo '<li>Address: '.$d->address.'</li>';
    echo '<li>District: '.$d->district.'</li>';
    echo '<li>City id: '.$d->city_id.'</li>';
    echo '<li>City name: '.$d->city.'</li>';
    echo '</dl>';
}
?>
```

Result in browser:

[image: Final output]

---

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: :) 
here my script

if ( isset($_GET['profile']) ) {

 $user_id = urldecode($library->hash_url("dekripsi", $_GET['profile']));
 $results = $proses->tampilUserId($user_id);
 foreach ($results as $key )
 {
  echo $key->username_user;
 }
}

Data kosong bg, tidak menampilkan apapun. But if i use echo $results[0]['email_user']; without foreach. i get error "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\laporan_app\user\_views\profile.php on line 34"

Comment: Saya coba script var_dump($results->email_user);
Hasilnya => Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\laporan_app\user\_views\profile.php on line 34
NULL

Comment: Nah itu kosong, SQL statement nya cek. Coba buang `INNER` nya. pake `JOIN` aja.

Comment: Hasilnya masih tetap sama bg.

Comment: Sorry lama, internet ngadat. `FROM $this->user` <-- mungkin ini bukan nama table? variable ut nama user kah? cb diganti pake string aja `nama_table` nya

Comment: $this->user = protected $user = "users"; //users nama tabel.

Comment: Coba di implement sample code nya. Cuma beda database aja ini.

Comment: Probably sir @Fred-ii- can spend a little time to give a shout